# an attribute 'Comparable on Front-end' and 'Used for Sorting in Product Listing' doesn't appear in view

Tags: magento-1.9

```
<?php
   foreach ($_item->getAttributes() as $_attribute):
   if ($_attribute->getIsComparable() == 1 || $_attribute->getUsedForSortBy() == 1):
      //attribute which is enabled both doesn't appears here.
      //Only either of them enabled appears
   endif;
endforeach;
```

In my code above the problem is, enabling either of them only appears to be true, enabling both doesn't appear into my `if` condition.

Comment: print_r($_attribute->getData()); ans see (used_for_sort_by) this is available in array?

Comment: @QaisarSatti No. It's not printing attributes fused for sorting. It's only printing attribute used for layered navigation.

Comment: update the answer check if it any help..

Answer (score 0):

try this code. i think it is not loading the all attribute data..

```
    <?php    


         foreach ($_item->getAttributes() as $_attribute):
echo $_attribute->getAttributeCode();
                        $attribute_details =
    Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute('catalog_product',    $_attribute->getAttributeCode());

                        if ($attribute_details->getIsComparable() == 1 and $attribute_details->getUsedForSortBy() == 1):
                          echo "worked";

       endif;
                endforeach;
```

Comment: i don't think so, because with only `$_attribute->getIsComparable() == 1` gets me inside. but an attribute with also using for sortable doesn't get me in.

Comment: have you tried that code?

Comment: Yes, this prints. But this only prints either them enabled. if i do `if ($_attribute->getIsComparable() == 1 && $attribute_details->getUsedForSortBy() == 1):` it prints nothing. This means attribute enabled both option doesn't enter the condition. And that is the question. :(

Comment: now your condition is working? i think you are working in layered navigation?

Comment: i have updated my comment above. please have a look.

Comment: if ($attribute_details->getIsComparable() == 1 && $attribute_details->getUsedForSortBy() == 1):  
use this code and check...

Comment: No, still the same. I'm in product listing page not in layered navigation. I'm printing attributes and values in table (in a seperate view other than grid/list).

Comment: update the answer kindly check you are getting the value on attribute code?